# JQuery Animation Issue on Drawing Multiple Arcs in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a clock application. I want to animate and draw the arcs on the canvas as they start, but it only draws one of the two arcs I've made. How can I ensure that during the animation both arcs are drawn? I want one mark drawn after another.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uawc8pu7/)

*HTML*

```
<canvas id="clock" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
```

*CSS*

```
body
{
    background: #1A4978;
}
```

*JS/JQuery*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('clock');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width/4;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var radius = 150;
var startAngle = 0;
var endAngle = 2*Math.PI;

var startAnimationDone = false;

if (startAnimationDone == true)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var second = date.getSeconds();
}

function update(start, end)
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#FF7519"; 

    context.arc(x , y, radius, start, end);
    context.lineWidth = 10; 
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#FFA319";
    radius = 160;

    context.arc(x , y, radius, start, end);
    context.lineWidth = 10; 
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var time = 0;
    var count = 0;
    function startAnimation() 
    {
        if (count <= 2)
        {
            time += 0.02;
            update(0, time*Math.PI);
            count += 0.02;
        }
    }
    setInterval(startAnimation, 10);
    startAnimationDone = true;
});
```

Comment: Looks like both your arcs are overlapping each other, if you change the radius of any one, 2 are appear. Do you want to start one arc after the other ends?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, that was what I was wanted for the animation. One arc drawing after another. Provide a solution if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uawc8pu7/3/

```
else if (!startAnimationDone) {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  startAnimationDone = true;
}
```

I added a check to see when your `startAnimationDone` variable changes to `true`, at which point the code will start a new animation for the other arc. The code can be cleaned up a bit as well :)